# Squid Proxy server configured as Global Proxy on iPad not allowing Gmail access

Tags: proxy, squid, gmail, g-suite, ipad

At my school we have installed a Squid proxy server to prevent users from logging in to their personal email ids by adding a header into all requests (as outlined [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1668854?hl=en)). The proxy itself works fine, and non-school domain email ids are blocked. So, the proxy has been configured as a Global HTTP Proxy on the iPads using the MaaS360 MDM. Everything works fine so far.

Gmail (the app) however does not work. When the app is opened, it loads for a bit and then shows "Something went wrong. Try again later."

[image: Error from the Gmail app]
*Error from the Gmail app*

Other Google Apps (Drive, Docs, Slides, Sheets) work fine. Sharing files also works, but the email notifying that something has been shared cannot be sent. I can sign in to Gmail Web through the browser though, and there it works fine.

Hence, I am lead to believe that Squid is restricting something to do with SMTP, POP, and IMAP, though that's just a guess. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi, have you checked the squid log, when starting gmail app? If the app is using the proxy, there should be some logs of interest to see I suppose. If there is no log entry, then gmail app is not using the proxy.

Comment: @Diamant I'll check it and let you know.